# MySQL query seems to be hanging

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn database and there was an online class where I had to load up the database with following SQL database source, well this is more like sample MYSQL database listed on their website so I think it's pretty safe to load.

https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db

Anyway, the query mentioned below is aiming to compute and give, employee with highest salary, employee_name, department_name grouped by each department. This query is taking really long, how can I identify the bottleneck?

I am using both native shell client and also Sequel Pro as well for executing same query and it seems like they are just hanging.

```
select employees.emp_no, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, salaries.salary, departments.dept_name 
from employees 
INNER JOIN salaries on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
INNER JOIN dept_emp on employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments on dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no 
where salaries.salary IN (select MAX(salaries.salary) 
                          from salaries 
                          GROUP BY departments.dept_no);

use employees;
```

Table schema:

```
mysql> desc dept_emp;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_no   | char(4) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc salaries;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| salary    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc departments;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dept_no   | char(4)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept_name | varchar(40) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You can't group by the value from another table. Move the bracket: `..... from salaries) GROUP BY departments.dept_no;` and maybe you have to add some condition for `MAX(salary)`.

Comment: I did moved that, bracket to `from salaries) GROUP BY departments.dept_no;` I got that ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'employees.employees.emp_no' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a IN clause based on a incomplete query

try using a inner join ON a subquery for max salary group by dept_id

```
select employees.emp_no
    , employees.first_name
    , employees.last_name
    , salaries.salary
    , departments.dept_name 
from employees 
INNER JOIN salaries on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
INNER JOIN dept_emp on employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments on dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no 
INNER JOIN (
  select departments.dept_no, max(salaries.salary)  max_sal
  from employees 
  INNER JOIN salaries on employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no 
  INNER JOIN dept_emp on employees.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no 
  INNER JOIN departments on dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no 
  group by departments.dept_no
) t on t.dept_no = departments.dept_no AND t.max_sal  = salaries.salary
```

Comment: ok I tried to execute your query as is, I got this error, `ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'employees.departments.dept_no'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: mysql version
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for macos10.14 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: ok that works, but can please you let me know why my implementation was failing and yours worked ?

Comment: In your subquery for max(salary)  is incomplete  you have not a join between departments and salaries  ...and the result ( i  doubt that return a result ... more probably an error)  could be tried on a cartesian product between the two table  +

Comment: so If I have to dissect what you have written in `select departments.dept_no, max(salaries.salary)  max_sal...` its like you are creating a table view containing just two items dept_no and max_sal, i.e. equivalent of answer to question, `please show me max salary by each dept_id` ? and then based on that query result you are making joins on dept_no AND  max_sal with table_view created right above ? 

EDIT: Thanking you, really appreciate your help.

Comment: exactly ... the subquery create a temp  table with the content you mention  ..  and this result is joined  to the main query